# Split list with string and numbers as string to two in order to float them

Tags: python, string, list, split, numbers

Hi i need to split a list that contains string. Some of the strings are words, other are numbers.

I have to float them

```
x = ['2','45','0.34','4.5','text','wse','56',]
```

what i tried:

```
FloatList = [x for x in Mylist if isinstance(x, float)]
```

but it prints empty list:

```
[]
```

Can you point me where am I wrong.

So I need to filter the words from the number strings, float the strings in sep. list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all string objects, `'1.2'` isn't `1.2`:

```
>>> type('1.2')
<class 'str'>
>>> type(1.2)
<class 'float'>
>>>
```

You should covert them to float object before check.

Since `float()` function will raise a `ValueError` if it failed to covert the string that you gives it, you could use `try...except` to catch that error:

```
>>> l = []
>>> x = ['2','45','0.34','4.5','text','wse','56'] 
>>> for i in x:
...     try:
...         l.append(float(i))
...     except ValueError:
...         pass

>>> l
[0.34, 4.5, 2, 45, 56]
```

Comment: Maybe OP wants also 2, 45 and 56 as floats, in which case you would need to remove the test about '.'

Comment: @DainDwarf: Yep, however I'm not sure, since OP want to get *floats*, not `float` and `int`.

Comment: Oh, I've edited. Remember accept an answer if it's helpful.

Comment: how can I accept it? Sorry I am totally new in this (my first question)

Comment: @GeorgeG.: No problem, just click the grey checkmark on the left side of my answer, it'll become green. Check our [tour] and [help] center for more details ;) (in this case, [tour] is enough).

Comment: done, thank you, I actually just was checking it with hope to find the answer